# How can I rename a folder with subfolders in node?

Tags: node.js, filesystems, directory, fs

I have a problem, I'm trying to rename a folder that contains subfolders, and I get the EPERM error.
Here what I'm doing.

```
const { projectID } = req.params
const newProject = req.body
if(fs.existsSync(`storage/${newProject.oldProjectID}`)) {
  fs.renameSync(`storage/${newProject.oldProjectID}`, `storage/${newProject.projectID}`)
}
```

Is there a way to rename only the main folder without having permissions errors?
thanks!

Comment: may be node process have no permission on those folder. try using sudo node script.js

Comment: i'm on windows, it make sense what you say but on windows i have no sudo, i'll try with admin rights. thanks.

Comment: no, same problem

Comment: try turning off your antivirus.

Comment: is not that. I think the problem is because i have subfolders, cause if the folder is empty i can change it.